# -bash: shell_exec: command not found , shell_exec is not running on linux terminal

Tags: php, linux

shell_exec is not running on linux terminal

try to run below commands

```
[root@localhost conf]# shell_exec
-bash: shell_exec: command not found
[root@localhost conf]# shell_exec("pwd")
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"pwd"'
[root@localhost conf]#
```

Comment: `shell_exec` is a PHP function, why are you trying to run it without PHP?

Comment: shell_exec is not running from PHP also

Comment: If your question is about PHP, please post what you tried, what you expected the results to be, and what the outcome was, including any error messages. If your question is about Linux, there are other forums that might be better suited.

Comment: You can’t write one language (php) into another language interpreter (bash) and expect it to just work. It’s immaterial to bash what the string is it’s simply invalid bash commands/syntax

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to execute PHP directly on the command line without using the PHP packaging, so the bash shell is attempting to execute it and doesn't recognize the PHP function.

You need to run `shell_exec()` in a PHP file or use the appropriate PHP CLI syntax. For example, you can pass `-r` to the `php` command, which allows you to run code.

```bash
myusername:~$ php -r 'echo shell_exec("pwd");'
/home/myusername
myusername:~$
```

Or you can use the built-in REPL.

```bash
myusername:~$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo shell_exec('pwd');
/home/myusername
php >
```

Also note the use of `echo` here since the successful result will return a string that we want to see.